# Spring Integration test Fails - missing Flyway configuration

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to write integration tests for my database, but the app crashes.

Here is my test:

```
@Test
    public void whenFindByCnp_thenReturnTransaction() {
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        // transaction setters
        entityManager.persist(transaction);
        entityManager.flush();

        // when
        Optional<Transaction> foundOptional = transactionRepository.findById(1L);
        if(!foundOptional.isPresent()){
            fail("The transaction was not saved");
        }

        Transaction foundTransaction = foundOptional.get();
        //asserts
    }
```

Here are the crash logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flywayInitializer
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration
    ...
```

Here is my Flyway configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String databaseUsername;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String databasePassword;

    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    Flyway flyway() {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        flyway.setDataSource(datasourceUrl, databaseUsername, databasePassword);
        return flyway;
    }
}
```

**Here are my questions:**

1. How can I disable flyway for integration tests, or what would be the correct way to solve this issue?
2. Do I have to migrate the database schema into the h2 test database?

Thank you!